# move distinct file types from subfolder to another folder

Tags: recursion, cmd, subdirectory

First of all, I have very little knowledge of the command line interface, so don't assume I know anything.

I have a folder containing subfolders and some of the subfolders also contain subfolders. The majority of the files in these folders are TIF, but there are some JPG as well. I would like to be able to write a command to select all of the .jpg files and move them to a separate folder.

I used something like this to move items in the main folder, but it didn't reach into the subfolders.

```
move C:\Users\Desktop\old_folder\*.jpg*  C:\Users\Desktop\new_folder
```

What can I add to this (or use something else) that will also find and move the .jpg files in the subfolders? I am using Windows 7 if that matters. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I will try something like this :

```
for /r "c:\source_directory\" %x in (*.jpg) do move "%x" "c:\target_directory\"
```

Comment: what does the %%x indicate? I got a message that said %%x was unexpected at this time.

Comment: %%x is the variable to store the path\filename.jpg found. I check for the error you get